# Daylight Savings Time and Microsoft Exchange woes

Tags: exchange-2003, windows, outlook-2003, daylight-saving

Ever since the switch from Standard Time to Daylight Time, the time on our e-mail messages has been ahead by one hour. This symptom has me wondering if the cause is improper configuration of daylight savings settings.

Since we're in a client/server environment, the clients synchronize with the server, and the server synchronizes with Boulder, Colorado. If I set both the server and the clients to automatically switch to daylight savings, the clients seem to regard the server as being set to Standard Time and set themselves an hour ahead of it, which is really two hours ahead. Should the server switch to daylight savings and the clients follow along on their next synchronization, or should the server stay on Standard Time and the clients switch over?

The system clock on the Exchange Server is currently displaying the correct time. How do I get the e-mail messages to display the correct time in Outlook?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have [Exchange Server 2003 SP2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=535bef85-3096-45f8-aa43-60f1f58b3c40), [2007 DST Update](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C16AEA4A-ED33-4CD9-A7C3-8B5DF5471B7A&amp;amp;amp;amp;displaylang=en&displaylang=en), and [Windows XP/2003 DST Update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928388) installed on the server?

If everything new is showing up at the right time, but old things are still the wrong time, you might have to use the [DST Update Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e343a233-b9c8-4652-9dd8-ae0f1af62568&displaylang=en), see it's instructions for more details of how it works and when specifically to use it.

Comment: In addition, make sure the clients have the applicable DST updates installed.

Comment: Exchange 2003 SP2 is definitely installed. Can't seem to find the two DST updates in the Add/Remove programs list of applied hotfixes, but this late in the year I'm not sure that would make a difference.

The system clock on the machine is correct, but all new e-mail is showing up with a time one hour later than actual.

Comment: I checked Automatic Updates and there's definitely a DST update of some sort in there, among other things. I'll have to apply these updates after hours and see how it goes.

Comment: Installed all the DST updates, but emails are still timestamped one hour later than the correct time.

Answer (score 1):

It sound's like you've got one group with the wrong time-zone.  When the clients request the time from the server, they should get the UTC (GMT) and then they should calculate the local time based upon their offset and Daylight Savings time from the Time Zone.

Comment: There is no grouping of computers here. All computers are experiencing this problem.